# What is the formal definition of $dI$? Where $I$ stands for current?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current, magnetostatics

Two days before my magnetostatics test and for some reason the idea of current just stopped making sense. I think I pin pointed the problem to $K$ and $J$, the so called surface and volume current density. Could anyone please write down the formal definition of $dI$? Because $dq/dt$ is not approaching 0 so can't be used here.

Comment: Why not approaching 0? $\Delta I = \Delta (\frac{dq}{dt})$. When the RHS tends to zero the LHS also tends to zero.

Comment: It is said that along the wire the current is completley identical and so dq(x)/dt-dq(x+dx)/dt=0 and so dI=0 and thats problematic. Could you explain according to which variable are you taking the limit?

Comment: In what context are you considering $dI$ (or is it $d\vec I$?)...a la Biot Savart Law. dq/dt implies the continuity equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a wire carries current $I$, $d\vec I$ means

$$d\vec I=Id\vec\ell$$

where $d\vec\ell$ is an infinitesimal segment of the (possibly curved) wire. Think of the vector $\vec\ell(\lambda)$ as pointing from some origin to various points on the wire, in a parametric description of the wire’s path. (For example, for a circular wire, the parameter $\lambda$ along the curve could be the angle $\theta$ around the circle.) Then $d\vec\ell$ is an infinitesimal vector *along* the wire.

Answer (score 0):

$\Delta q = \rho \Delta V$ where $\rho$ is the charge density and $V$ is the volume. If $\rho$ is constant, $$I = \frac{dq}{dt} = \rho \frac{dV}{dt}$$ If the cross sectional area $S$ is constant $$I = \rho S\frac{dx}{dt} = \rho Sv$$ where $v$ is the charge average velocity along the conductor. It is another form of defining $I$ for a usual wire.